# Varnish portable vlc script

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

In Varnish there are some differences between VCL 2.x and 3.0. Hash generation for example. In Varnish 2.x you'd do `req.hash += somevar` while in Varnish 3.x you would call `hash_data(somevar)`.

Is it possible to write portable Varnish scripts that work on both 2.x and 3.x? Can I `if` on the Varnish version for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible since Varnish compile vcl configs in C prior to start, so you should translate the config to the right version before or you will get a compile error.